# Let $f$ be a twice differentiable fuction in $x$, and such that $f'$ is also differentiable in $x$. Show that $f''(x)=(f')'(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable fuction in $x$, and such that $f'$ is also differentiable in $x$. Show that $f''(x)=(f')'(x)$.

Let $H(x)=f''(x),a(x)=f'(x),b(x)=(f')'(x)$

I want to show that $H=b$.

By definition of twice differentiable

$f(x+y)=f(x)+a(x)\cdot y+\dfrac{1}{2}H(x)y\cdot y+o_2(\|y\|^2)$

and by differentiability of the first derivative

$a(x+y)=a(x)+b(x)y+o_3(y)$

Also, since $f'$ is continuous in $x$

$f(x)=f(x+y-y)=f(x+y)-a(x+y)\cdot y+o^*(y)$

**Note:** $o(g(x))$ is a function such that

$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\|o(g(y))\|}{\|g(y)\|}=0$

Comment: Usually, "twice differentiable [at $x$]" is defined as "$f'$ is differentiable [at $x$]", and $f''(x) = (f')'(x)$ is the definition. What are the definitions you use?

Comment: It is twice differentiable if it is differentiable and there exists a square matrix $H(x)$ such that  $f(x+y)=f(x)+f'(x)\cdot y+\dfrac{1}{2}H(x)y\cdot y+o_2(\|y\|^2)$

Comment: Are you sure about this highly idiosyncratic definition of twice differentiability?

Comment: This is strictly related to what is called *converse of Taylor's theorem*. However be careful: the continuity of $H(x)$ with respect to $x$ is needed, otherwise counterexamples exist as in an answer below.